# How to assign parameter value to anonymous function in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

How `$item` variable has a value from `$products`

```
$products = $products->map(function($item){
    $item->getCustomPrices($this->user->client);
    $item->getMarkUpPrices($this->user->client);
    return $item;
});
```

Comment: what do you want ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Did you have a **question**?

Comment: @vishalpardeshi why $item variable contain value from product variable, how it work ?

Comment: My question is, how $item variable on anonymous contain object from $products array ?

Comment: First of all replace image with code

Comment: Intialized $item variable can't be used outside the function. You can re-instialized $item variable outside that function. Like
After Instializing $products

$item = $products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example to show you how to implement it 
 https://implode.io/Ce1azD

```
class Products
{
    protected $items = [];

    public function __construct($items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function map(callable $callback)
    {
        return array_map($callback, $this->items);
    }
}

$products = new Products([1, 2, 3, 4]);

return $products->map(function ($item) {
    return $item * 2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deep dive into laravel framework, the type of `$products` is [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html). It implements the `map` method and the [underlying implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L162) is:

```
public function map(callable $callback)
{
    $result = parent::map($callback);
    return $result->contains(function ($item) {
        return ! $item instanceof Model;
    }) ? $result->toBase() : $result;
}
```

The parent class of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` is [`Illuminate\Support\Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) and the [underlying implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L907) is:

```
public function map(callable $callback)
{
    $keys = array_keys($this->items);
    $items = array_map($callback, $this->items, $keys);
    return new static(array_combine($keys, $items));
}
```

It uses [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) method and it will apply the callback function to every value.

```
array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

Comment: Great, but how i can create my own map function ?

Comment: in what purpose you want to create your own map function? php already have build-in function `array_map` and laravel ships a lot helper functions (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) for collections out of the box and you don't need to implement your own!

Comment: I want build my own library for my website, i did't want create map function, just need to know how it work.

Comment: the basic thing is, you need to know how to read documentation (http://php.net/array_map), it already explains what you need to know in detail.

Comment: Ok, thks. That very helpful.